# Three entities hierarchical but in the third the first isn't accounted

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, core-data

I have an app with three `TableViews` and each is in a separate `ViewController`. I want pass the data from the `firstVC` to the `secondVC` to the `thirdVC`. Club -> Member -> transaction. If there is just one club, there is no problem. 
In the second club, there are the members from the second club, which has to be like this.

#### Problem

But if the user clicks on the member, there are the transactions from the members of the first club at the indexPath from the first club.

#### My thoughts

So I have to account the club as well to the transactions. But my solutions just threw errors.

So maybe you have a good solution. I found a solution here but this didin't helped me.
Here is my `TableView` code:

```swift
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return member?.transactions?.count ?? 0
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableViewTransaction.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "transactionCell", for: indexPath)
            if let transaction = member?.transactions?[indexPath.row] {

                cell.textLabel?.text = transaction.reason
                let moneystring = String(transaction.money)
                cell.detailTextLabel?.text = moneystring + " Fr."

                if transaction.money < 0.0 {
                    cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor.red
                }
                if transaction.money > 0.0 {
                    cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 110/255, blue: 0, alpha: 0.8)
                }


            }
            return cell
    }
```

Club fetch:

```swift
guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
            else {
            return
        }
        let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let fetchrequest: NSFetchRequest <Verein> = Verein.fetchRequest()

        do {
            clubs = try managedContext.fetch(fetchrequest)
            tableViewClub.reloadData()
        } catch {
            print("Could not fetch")
```

Member fetch:

```swift
 guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
                return
            }
            let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
            let fetchrequest: NSFetchRequest<Member> = Member.fetchRequest()

            do {
                members = try managedContext.fetch(fetchrequest)

                self.tableViewMember.reloadData()
            } catch {
                print("Could not fetch")
            }
```

Description of the App-

[image]

Comment: what errors you are getting show them

Comment: @V_rohit that club.members has no member transactions

Comment: Can you show your data mode?l (i.e the objects you have defined) And an example of the data you use to populate it. And the errors you're seeing.

Comment: @AshleyMills I added my core-data model to the question

Comment: @AshleyMills My tought was it to show the transaction, to which club they belong to because I just look for the member. I wanted to make member.transactions to club.members.transactions and this gave me the error that this is not member from it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UITableView cells are reused, so if you load a previously used cell -- with its label's already set -- could be used for a new one. Because you're only setting the cell's labels if a transaction is found, if no transaction is found the cell will simply show the data that was previously loaded. You need to do something like this.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableViewTransaction.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "transactionCell", for: indexPath)
    // clear the cell
    cell.textLabel?.text = "" // blank or whatever the default should be
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = ""

    // load any new data
    if let transaction = member?.transactions?[indexPath.row] {

        cell.textLabel?.text = transaction.reason
        let moneystring = String(transaction.money)
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = moneystring + " Fr."

        if transaction.money < 0.0 {
            cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor.red
        }
        if transaction.money > 0.0 {
            cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 110/255, blue: 0, alpha: 0.8)
        }


    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: This makes sense, but it didn‘t change anything. The data of the member at the indexPath 0.0 and the first club has the same data like the member at the indexPath 0.0 and the second club.

Comment: Then you're fetching the wrong data. Please include the code you're using to fetch the clubs and the members.

Comment: I added it to the question